# Extra unexpected characters Perl

Tags: perl

I'm reading a text file with multiple terms that are separated by newlines. For sample's sake, the two terms I have in the test file are

```
GO:0007161
GO:0061302
```

again separated by newline.

I read the file in and tried multiple things to get rid of the extra line:

```
our @GOTOSdata; 
open (GOTOS, "GOTempUpload/$ARGV[0]"); #or die ("Cannot open GOTreeOrderSearch file for read"); # read each eid from gene set into array to check if in dbfile
while (<GOTOS>) {
    $_ =~ y/\n//d;
    chomp ($_);
    push (@GOTOSdata, $_);
}
close (GOTOS);
chomp (@GOTOSdata);
```

I tried using both `chomp` and the regex expression to get rid of the newlines, but when I do `length($GOTOSdata[0])` and `length($GOTOSdata[1])`, the first element has the unexpected length of 11 (when it should be 10), and the second element has the expected length of 10.

If I input more `GO` terms, similar things happen: the last term is correct with 10 characters, but everything else is at 11.

How do I make sure that the string does not have anything else besides what is entered?

Comment: Is your data file created in Windows? Windows line separators use `\r\n`

Comment: Chomp removes the current input record separator, not the last character. The separator can be set by setting perl variable `$/ `

Comment: @Nate Thank you thank you thank you! The file was generated through entering in a textbox on my website which uses fwrite in PHP. DId not expect that it utilized \r\n. After altering the regex expression it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are processing a Windows text file on a foreign platform. You would see those symptoms because Windows text files have the two-character sequence CR LF as line terminators. I imagine there is no newline at the end of your last line

This program will read all of your file into array `@go_data` and remove all trailing white space from every element, which includes CR and LF as well as spaces and tabs

Note that you shouldn't use `our`, or put capital letters in local identifiers unless you have a very good reason

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my ($go_file) = @ARGV;

open my $go_fh, '<', "GOTempUpload/$go_file"
    or die qq{Unable to open "$go_file" for input: $!};

my  @go_data = <$go_fh>;
s/\s+\z// for @go_data;

close $go_fh;

say length for @go_data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your substitution and chomp with just this:

```
$_ =~ s/\r?\n//;
```

This should substitute either \n or \r\n with nothing. You could also consider removing all trailing whitespace like this:

```
$_ =~ s/\s+$//;
```

Comment: What `rtrim` function?

Comment: Thanks @Borodin, edited to remove that last suggestion. Mixed up my perl and php.

Comment: Okay. The [`Text::Trim`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Trim) module has an `rtrim` function and I assumed that that was what you meant. I was trying to say that you should cite the module. All it does is the `s/\s+\z//` that I recommended myself

Comment: Also, if you're running version 10 or better of Perl 5 then you can use the `\R` regex pattern. It matches anything classified as vertical whitespace in Unicode (LF, VT, FF, or CR) or the two-characters CR LF. That means `s/\R\z//` will "chomp" a record with Linux, Windows (network), or old-style Mac OS line endings equally well